# Teflon vs. Porcelain lined cookware (stove top)

Tags: cookware, teflon

We've had awful luck with non stick pots and pans no matter how much we spend on them. Most have been Teflon coated. We recently bought a bunch of "high quality", expensive, porcelain lined aluminum cookwares with enamel coated exteriors. I love the nonstick, easy cleaning so far. They are about 6 months old and no issues. Just wondering what others think of Porcelain vs Teflon cookware. Hope this will last much longer than what I've been use to.

Comment: Have to suspect something about your cooking practices contributes to any issues you are having with PTFE. I did finally replace my 20 year old frying pan with a new one a few years back (as much for the new, thicker aluminum part as for a new cooking surface.) I don't use the PTFE for high-heat applications it's unsuited to, and I use non-metallic utensils appropriate for not scratching up the surface. OTOH, the iron skillet I went off to college with is still going strong, but I use them for different things...

Comment: Possibly, I have changed a few things over time. When I brown meat for the slow cooker, I now use cast iron. I've warped a few aluminum non sticks doing this because I add water to the pan to get the browning out to add to the roast. Other than that it seems that most frying pans just wont stay flat and tend to shed their coatings withing 5 or 6 years.

Comment: This particular, inexpensive pan rocks: http://www.amazon.com/dp/B000GWG0T2/?tag=atkequippilot-20. According to America's Test Kitchen testing, porcelain is getting there, but the non-stick surface does not stay non-stick for as long as Teflon.

Comment: Dollars to doughnuts - you have been overheating them. We'll hope your new pans take that better and release less toxic chemicals (when overheated) as well. PTFE coatings above 500F are a bad, bad thing. When I'm going hot, I go cast iron.

Comment: This is the set we just got. It has a higher melting point with its PTFE Free type coating so I think it will do just fine for our purposes. http://www.kitchenviews.net/cookware-sets/wearever-pure-living-nonstick-ceramic-coating-ptfe-pfoa-free-dishwasher-safe-cookware-set-15-piece-red/